# creating a function for upload to save a specific path and check the limit of the folder

Tags: php

**i have a function to upload a file(video,audio, images and documents)  .. but i cant think of how to continue it.. I'm a beginner in programming by the way. and i want to upload a file and check the limit of the folder where i want to save the file if the folder reached the limit of 10 000 file inside,  if  it is true then it will create a new folder that has the same name but has a number in it (folder,folder 1 will be the next created)  and save it to the folder created..**

```
 function uploads($filename,$tempname){

      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $filename;
      $file_tmp = $tempname;
      $audioPath = "./archivestorage/upload/media/audio/";
      $videoPath = "./archivestorage/upload/media/video/";
      $imagePath = "./archivestorage/upload/media/images/";
      $documentPath = "./archivestorage/upload/document/";
      $file = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      if(empty($errors)==true) {



                    if($file ==='jpg')
                    {   
                         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$imagePath.$file_name);
                         echo "Success";
                         $return = $imagePath;


                    }
                    elseif($file ==='mp4')
                    {
                         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$videoPath.$file_name);
                         echo "Success";
                          $return = $imagePath;
                    }
                    elseif($file ==='mp3')
                    {
                         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$audioPath.$file_name);
                         echo "Success";
                          $return = $imagePath;
                    }
                    elseif($file ==='jpeg')
                    {
                         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$imagePath.$file_name);
                         echo "Success";
                          $return = $imagePath;
                    }
                    else if($file ==='docx')
                    {
                         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$documentPath.$file_name);
                         echo "Success";
                          $return = $imagePath;
                    }
                    elseif($file ==='png')
                    {
                         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$imagePath.$file_name);
                         echo "Success";
                          $return = $imagePath;
                      }
                   else{
                 print_r($errors);
                    }
                    }
```

Comment: Hello, please post your 'function to upload a file' to your question so we can help you ! Please also provide what you thougth, and why it was not fixing your problem ! Thank you, and have a nice day on SO !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am giving you simple demonstration here.may be its not correct as per your need. remember class `FilesystemIterator` will work if your php version is above `5.3`

```
    if($file ==='jpg')
    {  
     $folderChk = new FilesystemIterator($imagePath, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS)
        if (iterator_count($folderChk)<10000) {
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$imagePath.$file_name);
            echo "Success";
            $return = $imagePath;
        }
        else{
            $imagePath=$imagePath." 1 " ;
            mkdir($imagePath, 0777, true);
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$imagePath.$file_name);
            echo "Success";
            $return = $imagePath;

    }
}
```

if its not work you can use `glob()` try like that

```
if($file ==='jpg')
{   $filecount = 0;
    $files = glob($imagePath . "*");
    if ($files){
     $filecount = count($files);
    }
    if ($filecount<10000) {
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$imagePath.$file_name);
         echo "Success";
        $return = $imagePath;
    }
    else{
        $imagePath=$imagePath." 1 " ;
        mkdir($imagePath, 0777, true);
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$imagePath.$file_name);
        echo "Success";
        $return = $imagePath;
    }



}
```

if you want to create multiple folder you should try like this

```
$imagePath = "./archivestorage/upload/media/images/";   
    $folderCount = 0;
    $folder = scandir($imagePath);//read directory 
        if ($folder){
            $folderCount = count($folder)-2;//count dir
        }
    $file = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(empty($errors)==true) {
        if($file ==='jpg')
        {   
            $filecount = 0;
            if (is_dir($imagePath)) {
                $files = glob($imagePath . "*");
                if($files){
                    $filecount = count($files);
                }
                if ($filecount<10000) {
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$imagePath.$file_name);
                    echo "Success";
                    $return = $imagePath;
                }
                else
                {
                    for ($i = 1; $i <=$folderCount ; $i++) {
                        if(is_dir($imagePath." ".$i)) {
                            $imagePath=$imagePath." ".$i;
                            $files = glob($imagePath . "*");
                            if ($files){
                                $filecount = count($files);
                            }
                            if ($filecount<10000) {
                                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$imagePath.$file_name);
                                echo "Success";
                                $return = $imagePath;
                                exit();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $imagePath=$imagePath."  "$i;
                            mkdir($imagePath, 0777, true);
                            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$imagePath.$file_name);
                            echo "Success";
                            $return = $imagePath;
                            exit();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried your code above bro..  and it says Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant '­SKIP_DOTS' .. wat does it mean

Comment: what is your php version

Comment: PHP Version => 7.0.22 im using ubunto

Comment: bro  solution that you gave me..is it  running in your computer? im really a beginner on this

Comment: i really need a  sample code for this. and i dont have an idea how to make the folder create new folder if the directory is already reached its limit and create new directory

Comment: is it possible that my php version is the problem /

Comment: sure why. not. bro .. youre best

Comment: i havent tried the code above bro..  is it running successfully in your computer bro?

Comment: oh..thank u  so much.. ill try it now... gonna open my computer.. ty bro

Comment: the folder is  already running but  the image that will be stored in it  cant  execute bro..

Comment: i mean..bro,  i cant  increment new folder if the folder  reached new limit... maybe i should use looping for that .. do you have a sample on it bro?